# How to Fix a MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

CREATE  TABLE `test`.`TableOne` (

`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`Empno` INT NULL ,

`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Balance` DECIMAL(6,2) NULL ,

`Place` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) );

CREATE  TABLE `test`.`TableTwo` (

`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`Date` DATE NULL ,

`Empno` INT NULL ,

`Receipt` DECIMAL(6,2) NULL ,

`Payment` DECIMAL(6,2) NULL ,

`Status` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) );

INSERT INTO `test`.`tableone` (`Empno`, `Name`, `Balance`, `Place`) VALUES (100, 'John', '1500', 'Wasinton DC');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tableone` (`Empno`, `Name`, `Balance`, `Place`) VALUES (101, 'Joselin', '1000', 'Dexcity');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tableone` (`Empno`, `Name`, `Balance`, `Place`) VALUES (102, 'Rusfal', '0', 'Donxes');
INSERT INTO `test`.`tableone` (`Empno`, `Name`, `Balance`, `Place`) VALUES (103, 'Raser', '100', 'versity');

INSERT INTO `test`.`tableone` (`Empno`, `Name`, `Balance`, `Place`) VALUES (104, 'rse', '2500', 'sew');

INSERT INTO `test`.`TableTwo` (`Date`, `Empno`, `Receipt`, `Payment`, `Status`) VALUES ('2016-08-15', 100, '1000', '0', 'OK');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TableTwo` (`Date`, `Empno`, `Receipt`, `Payment`, `Status`) VALUES ('2016-08-15', 100, '0', '1000', 'OK');

INSERT INTO `test`.`TableTwo` (`Date`, `Empno`, `Receipt`, `Payment`, `Status`) VALUES ('2016-08-17', 101, '0', '2000', 'OK');

INSERT INTO `test`.`TableTwo` (`Date`, `Empno`, `Receipt`, `Payment`, `Status`) VALUES ('2016-08-18', 103, '100', '0', 'NOT OK');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TableTwo` (`Date`, `Empno`, `Receipt`, `Payment`, `Status`) VALUES ('2016-08-19', 100, '1500', '0', 'OK');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TableTwo` (`Date`, `Empno`, `Receipt`, `Payment`, `Status`) VALUES ('2016-08-20', 100, '0', '1000', 'OK');

Then I need Output this

starting date '2016-08-18' ending date '2016-08-20'

Empno   Name    Place             OB           CB
100     John    Wasinton DC     2400        2000 
101     Joselin Dexcity             1000           0
102     Rusfal  Donxes              0                0

etc
103
104

also

Condition
OB less amount get less than starting Date based on status OK Only

forumula
OB=Balance+Receipt-Payment

Condition
CB calculation from date to date based on status OK Only

forumula
CB=Balance+Receipt-Payment

Comment: You don't `GROUP BY` anything so your sum is entirely correct in the eyes of MySQL (on many others you'd get an error)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,sum(amount1)as amount1,sum(Receipt) as Receipt,sum(payment) as payment,
sum(amount1)+sum(Receipt)-sum(payment) as Total,nameid,b.name 
FROM test.mas as a left join test.trans as b on a.id=b.nameid GROUP BY a.id;
```